# how to store User logs on a large server best practice

Tags: mongodb, logback

From my experience this is what i come up with.

Im currently saving Users and Statistic classes into the MongoDb and everything works grate.

But how do i save the log each user generate?

Was thinking to use the LogBack `SiftingAppender` and delegate the log information
to separate MongoDb `Collections`. Like every MongoDb `Collection` have the id of the user.
That way i don't have to create advanced mapreduce query's since logs are neatly stacked.

Or use `SiftingAppender` with a FileAppender so each user have a separate log file.

I there is a problem with this if the MongoDB have one million Log Collections each one named with the User Id. (is it even possible btw)

If everything is stored in the MongoDb the MongoDb master-slave replication makes
it easy if a master node dies.

What about the FileAppender approach. Feels like there will be a hole lot of log files
to administrate. One could maybe save them in folders according to Alphabet. Folder A
for user/id with names/id starting with A.

What are other options to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Embedded Documents and have one Document for each user with an array of embedded documents containing log files. You can also benefit from sharding if collections get large.

Comment: yes that's a good ide. Already have several other Embedded Documents. Every user have his log Embedded of course. It felt tempting to create a hole new Db only for the logs. Kind of separation the log from rest, dunno

Comment: If your worried about overhead you can use an array of DBRef's (ObjectIds) to Seperate log Documents in a different collection so that all the logs aren't loaded every time you query a user document.

Comment: Do you know if slf4j, log4j, LogBack, etc kan instead of appending to file or console can insert the Log entry on-the-fly into the Embedded Documents like you describe. Have a feeling i have to make some custom MongoDBAppender something??

Answer (score 2):

On your qn of 1M collections, the default namespace file for a db is 16MB which allows about 24000 namespaces (12000 collections + their _id indexes). More info [on this website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections.)

And you can set maximum .ns (namespace) file size to 2GB with --nssize option, which will allow probably 3072000 namespaces.